# How to query by asset type in Content Builder Api

Tags: rest-api, content-builder

I want to get assets filtered by assetType using request like this:

```
POST /asset/v1/content/assets/query
"query":
{
        "property":"assetType:id",
        "simpleOperator":"equals",
        "valueType":"int",
        "value":"207"
},
```

But it returns empty array (I have assets with assetType = 207 in my account). Could you help me and tell how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 3):

Here's [information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset-model.htm) about the assetType property, and here is a [list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/base-asset-types.htm) of the asset types. There hasn't been documentation released yet regarding filtering for these routes, but this should work in the payload:

```
{
    "query": {
        "property": "assetType.id",
        "simpleOperator": "equals",
        "valueType": "int",
        "value": 207
    }
}
```